# How to make NSTimer continue running even after a force quit

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nstimer

In my app, the title of a button changes after 30 seconds of pressing the button. However, if I force quit my app by closing it through the multitasking menu, the timer stops, and when I open the app, I have to tap on the button again to start the timer. How can I use NSUserDefaults to make the timer continue running even after a force quit? Thanks

Comment: Do you need the timer to actually be running, or do you just need to know the time since it started? You could save the start time and use it when the app restarts.

Comment: @DougMead So I can basically remove NSTimer right? Is there a way to record the date and time when the button was pressed, and then when the app is opened again, check this- if the date is the same, then check if time is more than start time + 30 seconds, and if date is more than start date, then straight away change the title of the button. How can I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405079/how-to-run-timer-thought-the-app-entered-background-or-is-terminated

Answer (score 0):

There is the [applicationWillTerminate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate%3A) method. When it is called, you can store the remaining time on the timer in your `NSUserDefualts` and then restart the timer when the app launches again.

Comment: But I want the timer to continue running even when the app is terminated. I don't want it to pause.

Comment: If the app is terminated then that is not possible. When the app is terminated **everything** you have in memory, including timers, is dropped. You won't be able to run anything else until the app is opened again.

Comment: So can I do something about what I mentioned in the comments of the question above in reply to DougMead's comment?

Comment: Yeah like I said store the time left on the timer (or the time). When the app opens compare the time and see if it is passed the time that the timer would've fired and perform the action.

Comment: Yes, then you will want to get the data from the `NSUserDefaults` (or CoreData if you choose) when the app starts again.

Comment: Surely rather than storing time left, he wants to store the time (/`NSDate`) at which the timer should fire? Vaguely related: I started the built-in stopwatch on, probably, my iPhone 3G and then, because I was restoring each new device from iTunes backups, it ostensibly kept running across at least my 3Gs, 4 and 4s. But at some point I started configuring each phone as fresh, and/or possibly a new version of iOS reset things, so sadly it is no longer [pretending to be] running.

Comment: Either way it's just a matter of storing and comparing the expected value

Comment: How can I create a constant which specifically holds the date at which the button is pressed, and then a constant which specifically holds the date at which the button should change it's title? I tried a few things but none of them worked.

Comment: Button pressed: record current `NSDate`. calculate date X amount of time in the future. Store the new calculated date in `NSUserDefaults`. On subsequent app launch, retrieve date and compare.

Comment: @Slayter I tried some stuff, but none of it worked. Can you send me the code? I'm new to NSDate and timers and stuff. I've tried everything I could for hours.

Comment: @Slayter Also, why is this code not working?- `let timeInterval = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(timeInterval, forKey: "timeInterval")
let finalInterval = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("timeInterval")`
It gives me 0