# Is this correct for a NSTimer to get run on the main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

Hello I wanted to run a NSTimer on the main thread im not sure if they are run on the main thread by default or I have to do a special implementation ? thanks to anyone who could help

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {

        NSTimer *minutePassed;
    }

    - (void)adViewDidLoad
    {

    minutePassed = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(callMinutedPassed) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    }

    -(void)callMinutePassed
    {
    NSLog("Minute Passed");
    }
```

Comment: This is the right way to schedule a timer. A few unrelated observations: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/e8ec70f49f0c112ffdd7c4566eedc13e

Comment: if i have something like this and the app goes into background does the countdown keep counting to 60 seconds or does it get paused ?, minutePassed = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(callMinutePassed) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642036/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/26405492/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/34497360/1271826...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for `scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats)` states `Creates a timer and schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode.`. That means in your instance, that it is running on the main thread. I'm assuming when you say `-(void)adViewDidLoad` you mean `-(void)viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: if i have something like this and the app goes into background does the countdown keep counting to 60 seconds or does it get paused ?, minutePassed = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(callMinutePassed) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];